# Roll-up status from child to parent in elastic query

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, rollup

I have following structure in the my elastic index.

`Header`
`{`
`Header Attributes`
`"Lines":`
`[`
`{`
`"LineStatus": "Action Needed"`
`},`
`{`
`"LineStatus": "Delayed"`
`},`
`,`
`{`
`"LineStatus": "On-Track"`
`}`
`]`
`}`

Based on the line status I wanted to roll up to one status on the header during query time and filter rows based on the headers status.

Following is the logic.

if one of the lines has action needed then header status would be action needed.
if no lines has action needed but one of the lines has Delayed then header status would be delayed.

How can we build such query, for some reason we have restriction on runtime fields usage in the index we can't use them in our product, is there any other way we can achieve the same.

Thanks in Advance.

I have used script_fields but I was not able to use them in the filter.